# WCF RIA Services DomainService error: ContractDescription has zero operations; a contract must have at least one operation

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am developing a small instant messaging application that makes use of few DomainServices on the server side. Trying to access the domain service URL, I encounter the following error:

*"ContractDescription 'AppInitService' has zero operations; a contract must have at least one operation".*

The domain service Url is this one:
http://givemeword.net/chat/Services/IM-Chat-UI-Web-DomainServices-AppInitService.svc

You can find the domain service class below:

```
namespace Chat.UI.Web.DomainServices
{
    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public class AppInitService : DomainService
    {
        private System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal _user;
        private readonly Chat.UI.Web.Services.AppInitService _appInitService;

        public AppInitService()
        {
            _appInitService = new Chat.UI.Web.Services.AppInitService();
        }

        public InitUserSettingsDTO InitUserSettings(Guid userId)
        {
            var initUserSettingsDTO = new InitUserSettingsDTO();

            return initUserSettingsDTO;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using a complex type as the return type of the only function of the domain service.

What I can not figure out is why on my testing Windows Server 2012 (not a development machine, just a virtual machine used for testing) or on my development machine everything runs without any problem, but on the hosting account it raise the error above.

Does anyone has any idea about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the [Invoke] attribute to your InitUserSettings method:

```
    [Invoke]
    public InitUserSettingsDTO InitUserSettings(Guid userId)
    {
        var initUserSettingsDTO = new InitUserSettingsDTO();

        return initUserSettingsDTO;
    }
```

Make sure your web.config is set up as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426912(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll check the provided url. The question still persists: why it is working on my machines? I suspect that it is the WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP1 or SP2 that it is not installed on the hosting account.

Comment: The fact that the service is responding makes me think your setup is ok. RIA services are designed to return "entity" objects in an object graph. If your dto does not have a key property, then it is a poco and the service method needs to be decorated with the invoke attribute to work.

Comment: Thank you again Rob. Everything was just fine with the web.config. Adding a dummy function with [Invoke] attribute into the domain class indeed solved the problem with accessing its Url. But trying to access functions returning complex type still resulted into "Not found" errors on the client side.

Comment: If your DTO is not an entity, you need to add attributes as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx or you can make your DTO an entity by adding the key attribute: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx

Comment: Useful information, Rob. It helped me find the answer to my problem. Thanks for support!

Answer (score 0):

Being exasperated with this strange situation and the low support I received from the web hosting company, I have tried the same thing with another web provider. As I was thinking, it was working this time with no problems, so my assumption that the original provider had poor support for WCF RIA Services (or maybe other unidentified problem) was correct.